# Thread not behaving correctly

Tags: java, multithreading

I wonder if anyone can help me to understand where I could be going wrong with this code; Basically I'm working on a tutorial and calling the class below from another class - and it is getting the following error;

Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.newdawn.spaceinvaders.TCPChat.run(TCPChat.java:322)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I realize the error is being flagged in another class- but I have tested the other class with a small class which sets up a separate thread - and it works fine, but as soon as I try and implement a new thread in this class - it causes all sorts of problems. Am I setting up the thread correctly in this class?

Basically I can set up a thread in this class, with a test loop and it's fine, but when I bring in the functionality of the rest of the game it sometimes hangs, or does not display at all.

Any suggestions on where I could be going wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: 621 lines of code? hey, what could be relevant?

Comment: Give the code of `TCPChat` instead of what you gave.

Comment: http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=155

Comment: aologies for the masses of code, I have been doing my best to et my head around the problem for the past couple of days, and I have got to the point I can't see the wood for the trees with this - I have read up and tried many related tutoriials, but i can't seemt o get past this problem. I realise it's just getting to grips with java  at the moment is probably not helping :)

Comment: The stacktrace points to line 322 of the class TCPChat but you have posted "only" the first 190 lines of this class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`NullPointerException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) is the most common exception and is very easy to identify. It occurs on a number of cases (listed in the linked javadoc), but the most common is calling a method on a `null` object. For example if you have:

```
String str = null;
str.substring(2,4); // str is null and NullPointerException is thrown
```

So go to the line of code indicated by the stacktrace (TCPChat.java:322), and check whether there is a `null` object there on which methods are invoked. If there are, make sure they are not `null`, or make an `if` statement that checks if `if (obj != null)` so that the code is not executed.

**Update:** it seems the `connectButton` is `null`. You have to call `initOptionsPane()` before you call start the thread.

Comment: I stuck the chat class up there, thanks for the advice, I will have a look and see if I can see what the problem is at 322.

Comment: Thanks - I'm having a look now.

Answer (score 3):

> java.lang.NullPointerException at org.newdawn.spaceinvaders.TCPChat.run(TCPChat.java:322)

Open `TCPChat.java` source file, peek to line 322 and look around in this particular line where the dot operator `.` is been used to access some object reference. Something like:

```
someObject.doSomething();
```

A `NullPointerException` on this line means that `someObject` is `null`. You cannot access or invoke *nothing*. To solve such a problem, you just need to ensure that `someObject` is **not** null at that moment:

```
if (someObject == null) {
    someObject = new SomeObject();
}
someObject.doSomething();
```

Or, you need to skip the whole invocation when it is `null`:

```
if (someObject != null) {
    someObject.doSomething();
}
```

This has by the way **nothing** to do with threads. It's just a programming error, as with every other [`RuntimeException`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html).

Comment: (+1). It's at least the second time today someone doesn't understand NPE .. I just wonder how hard it is to open the javadoc. I can't remember having troubles with NPE when I started programming..

Comment: @Bozho: you have programmers and programmers. @ivor: you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the title of this question: The thread is behaving correctly. It's your code in the thread that is not ;)